# Apache Solr java tutorials

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, apache, solr

I am new to Apache solr and somehow whatever google search I am doing, I am not able to understand the tutorials on solr.

I want to develop simple search using Solr and Java on MySQL. Currently I am able to run solr on tomcat. But not sure how to proceed using solr libraries.

Does anybody know tutorials that I can refer to ?

Comment: You might want to check out the books available:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/books.html

Comment: @SidCool yes books are there.. but any video or post will make work faster at the current moment...

Comment: I tried searching it and all I could find is this video below:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRQeYiuPgMA

Comment: @SidCool I have actually seen that video previously .. but I needed something like actual java code example using Solr libraries..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find any exact example that you want. Here I will try to show you a way to start.

Firstly, since you have a running solr, you should configure it to index data in Mysql. You can refer to the following tutorials/blog posts to learn how to configure Solr to index Mysql data.

- [Using Solr / Lucene for full text search with MySQL DB](http://www.cabotsolutions.com/2009/05/using-solr-lucene-for-full-text-search-with-mysql-db/)
- [IMPORTING A MYSQL DATABASE INTO APACHE SOLR](http://entropytc.com/importing-a-mysql-database-into-apache-solr/)
- [Apache Solr MySQL Sample Data Config](http://saylinux.net/story/0010629/apache-solr-mysql-sample-data-config)
- [nstalling Solr Tomcat for MySql Indexing on Ubuntu](http://www.wheelsandcogs.co.uk/2011/01/13/solr-tomcat-mysql-ubuntu/)

Then by using Solrj (Solr Java Driver) you can index/query data. You can find some getting started tutorials below.

- [Solj tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)
- [Using SolrJ](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Using+SolrJ)
- [Indexing with Solrj](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2012/02/14/indexing-with-solrj/)
- [Solrj example](http://wiki.constellio.com/index.php/Solrj_example)
- [Using Solrj – A short guide to getting started with Solrj](http://e-mats.org/2008/04/using-solrj-a-short-guide-to-getting-started-with-solrj/)

Comment: Thank you for the links.. I will try those... something better than nothing..