# solr.Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [solrconfig.xml] requestHandler: missing mandatory attribute 'class'

Tags: java, mysql, solr, lucene, search-engine

I try to introduce with apache Solr. At this resource I find out popular question: [Apache Solr java tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586715/apache-solr-java-tutorials)

I tryed to start from 1 link:
[simple example](http://www.cabotsolutions.com/2009/05/using-solr-lucene-for-full-text-search-with-mysql-db/)

When I reached the point

> 5. Stop and restart solr instance. Check if there are any jdbc errors, this could happen if the jdbc drivers are not properly installed.

I see next trace(last version):

```
      2875 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  Ц F
ailed to load file D:\solr2\example\solr\collection1\solrconfig.xml
2875 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  Ц U
nable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file D:\solr2\exampl
e\solr\collection1\solrconfig.xml
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java
:525)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [solrconfig.xml] requestHandler: missing
mandatory attribute 'class'
        at org.apache.solr.util.DOMUtil.getAttr(DOMUtil.java:80)
        at org.apache.solr.util.DOMUtil.getAttr(DOMUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.solr.core.PluginInfo.<init>(PluginInfo.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readPluginInfos(SolrConfig.java:296)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.loadPluginInfo(SolrConfig.java:281)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:219)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java
:522)
        ... 11 more
2875 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  Ц n
ull:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:
977)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:601)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file D:\s
olr2\example\solr\collection1\solrconfig.xml
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java
:525)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [solrconfig.xml] requestHandler: missing
mandatory attribute 'class'
        at org.apache.solr.util.DOMUtil.getAttr(DOMUtil.java:80)
        at org.apache.solr.util.DOMUtil.getAttr(DOMUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.solr.core.PluginInfo.<init>(PluginInfo.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readPluginInfos(SolrConfig.java:296)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.loadPluginInfo(SolrConfig.java:281)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:219)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java
:522)
        ... 11 more

2875 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  Ц user.dir=D:\solr
2\example
2875 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  Ц SolrDispatchFilt
er.init() done
2922 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  Ц Started SocketCo
nnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

Can you help me?

**update**

[image]

solrconfig.xml:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/2b67m83v5cy05zd/solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not finding your solr config file:

**Could not load config file D:\solr2\example\solr\collection1\solrconfig.xml**

Double check to see if your solr config file is in the specified directory.

Comment: from trail: **3. Edit file solrconfig.xml which is located in solr/example/solr/conf directory**

Comment: I copy my config to the folder but I see old stacktrace