# how to post file in Solr using java code

Tags: solr4

I am trying to post/uplooad a file to Solr using java code by passing suitable input.
So is there any such options/method to implement it in Solr 4.7.2.

Comment: Can I use Solrj for implementing the above one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Solrj, here are some links from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11590165/2939759):

- [Solj tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)
- [Indexing with Solrj](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2012/02/14/indexing-with-solrj/)
- [Solrj example](http://wiki.constellio.com/index.php/Solrj_example)
- [Using Solrj – A short guide to getting started with Solrj](http://e-mats.org/2008/04/using-solrj-a-short-guide-to-getting-started-with-solrj/)

More links:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ

Comment: Thanks Matt Wanchap for suggestion